# Loading Google Fonts over HTTPS still give MixedContent error

Tags: html, css, ssl, https

I recently added SSL to my website but it keeps giving me the error:

```
Mixed Content: The page at 'https://youtubehulp.nl/comingsoon/' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure stylesheet 'http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Source+Sans+Pro:300,300italic,400,400italic,600,600italic,700,700italic,900,900italic'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.
```

While the link to the fontsheet is `https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Source+Sans+Pro:300,300italic,400,400italic,600,600italic,700,700italic,900,900italic`

I also tried downloading the file and then loading the local version but that didn't work either.

Tried code:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Source+Sans+Pro:300,300italic,400,400italic,600,600italic,700,700italic,900,900italic">

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Source+Sans+Pro:300,300italic,400,400italic,600,600italic,700,700italic,900,900italic">

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="font.css">

@import url("//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Source+Sans+Pro:300,300italic,400,400italic,600,600italic,700,700italic,900,900italic");

@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Source+Sans+Pro:300,300italic,400,400italic,600,600italic,700,700italic,900,900italic");
```

Also made sure all links in the font file are HTTPS

I hope someone can help me with this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a simple typo in your stylesheet https://youtubehulp.nl/comingsoon/css/style.css:

```
@import url("https//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=…");
                 ^^
```

The `:` is missing after the protocol name. Therefor, it is a *relative* URL, and when the browser makes an absolute URL out of that using the current URL, the result naturally is https://youtubehulp.nl/comingsoon/css/https//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Source+Sans+Pro:300,300italic,400,400italic,600,600italic,700,700italic,900,900italic

And requesting *that* URL makes your server issue a redirect to http://www.youtubehulp.nl/comingsoon – and *that* is the origin of the mixed content warning.

Comment: Requesting https://youtubehulp.nl/comingsoon/css/style.css again, even with [ctrl]+[f5] to circumvent browser cache, still shows the typo. Either you did not upload the change, or there’s still some caching going on on your server(?).

Comment: Probably server chaging

Comment: It shows the correct lnk using http://www.youtubehulp.nl/comingsoon/ but not when using it without www

Comment: `http://youtubehulp.nl/comingsoon/css/style.css` and `http://www.youtubehulp.nl/comingsoon/css/style.css` still deliver different content. Why, only you can find out, only you know your server setup etc.